# How do I get TInyMCE to accept relative image paths without a leading slash

Tags: relative-path

We use TinyMCE on Drupal platform. Content is formatted in an external editor (Dreamweaver) and then dropped into TinyMCE for final tweaks that are easier to do in TinyMCE.

Images are stored on the Drupal server and the image path is relative.  The issue is this:

Sometimes images have a forward slash in the path and sometimes they don't. Thus:
/myimages/image.jpg OR myimages/image.jpg

I should add that the folder is in the root directory. Thus: mywebsite.com/myimages

Either way, Drupal references the image from the correct folder.

TinyMCE however, will only display the image in the editor if there is a forward slash. Otherwise there is just an empty box. Easy enough to change the link when we see that, but still, easier if TinyMCE would just accept that as relative link.

I know! Why don't the images ALWAYS have forward slash. 'Cause stuff happens. Sometimes it happens in Dreamweaver.

In any case, is there a way to configure TinyMCE to treat an path with or without the leading slash the same?

Thanks

I have tried researching this but haven't found anything with this kind of description.